# Modify form action based on user input in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I have a radio button

```
<?php echo $this->Form->radio('viewoptions', array('process' => 'Print to Screen',
     'download' => 'Download to Text File')); ?>
```

Inside a form

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Recipe', array('action'=>'[process or download]')); ?>
```

I would like to call the appropriate action based on whether the user checked "Print to Screen" or "Download to Text File."

How could I go about this?

Comment: You need to write a javascript function, this function should be dispatch in onClick event of your radio button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do that real-time, you'd have a javascript dependency on the client side. It's best to verify what course of action to take in your controller logic. Just create an overall handler and point to that in your form. So add it like this in your View:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Recipe', array('action' => 'handler'));
```

And in your controller:

```
public function handler() {
    // Sanity check
    if (!isset($this->request->data['Recipe']['viewoptions'])) { 
        throw new InternalErrorException(__('No viewoptions passed'));
    }

    // Make the decision
    switch ($this->request->data['Recipe']['viewoptions']) {
        case 'process':
            // Run the process method logic
            $this->process();
            break;
        case 'download':
            // Run te download method logic
            $this->download();
            break;
        default:
            throw new InternalErrorException(__('Unknown viewoptions passed'));
    }
}
```